# Wordpress Export post with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, advanced-custom-fields

I've built a page creator using a mix of layouts with the flexible layout and repeater options with advanced custom fields. I was wondering when you create a page or a post(I also used the same concept for post) can you export the data of the post into a JSON or XML file(That holds the same structure as the post or page).

This will be really helpful since I will have to migrate the post into another WordPress site.

I appreciate any help. :)

Comment: you have to do it only once .. or needs to fetch the records from this site to other site?

Comment: Hi Prakash, Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I will be moving the content to the site and then have to move more content once I finished developing the site. In the meantime there will be users creating content in the site